# Error in simulator when try run an app

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, ios-simulator, uitableview

I created app with using storyboards. My app has a **table, some buttons and labels**.

When I try to run my app simulator generates an error: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x719de00'`

`UIViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` means that I can't use "numberOfRowsInSection" with "UIViewController"?

I tried to use "UITableViewController" instead but with this controller I can't locate the buttons and labels in right place for me.

**What I do wrong?**

Thanks.

Comment: Ok well try. keep it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you Add the UITableView and set Datasource and Delegate, we must use some UITableview Delegate Methods. such as NumberOfRowsInSection, NumberOfSection, and so on. 
  Kindly Use the Essential Delegate Methods or Remove the UItableView.

Comment: Yes, I know that I should link dataSource and delegate to table view. I opened View Controller -> Connections Inspector -> Referencing Outlets: there are `dataSource->table view` and `delegate->table view`

Comment: You Add return count for NumberOfSection such as >=1?

Comment: `-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [array count];
}`

Comment: Plase check your UIViewController has the protocol declaration as this: <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

Comment: Check NumberOfSectionsInTableview. how many you return for section?

Comment: Can I use "numberOfRowsInSection" with "UIViewController", right?

Comment: Yes sure, - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
 
return [listOfItems count];
}

Comment: [listOfItems count] is your wish. default you must return 1.

Comment: It's working or check the Web site, hope it must help for you.

Comment: By the way, if I do the same project without using storyboards everything ok. Maybe I should do by using storyboard something differently?

Comment: I resolved my problem! I just forget to select the class in View Controller :) OMG! :( So much headache for little mistake!

Answer (score 0):

You need to delegate the `UITableView` to the `UIViewController`, open the Connections inspector and drag the "`delegate`" and "`dataSource`" entries to the main view controller on the storyboard.

Comment: Yes, I know that I should link dataSource and delegate to table view. I opened View Controller -> Connections Inspector -> Referencing Outlets: there are `dataSource->table view` and `delegate->table view`